# Is it possible to generate "client id" keys in Google Developer Console through API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, api-key

To use Google APIs I need to create client ID for my web application by logging into Google Developer Console.

Previously, you could specify the redirect back URL in the request itself. Now you have to specify it in the key itself.

This has introduced a problem for us.

New subscription group that signs up with us, gets its own subdomain. Is there any way to automate the client ID generation so that as soon the user hits submit, a key pair is generated and stored in the DB. When the user comes to Google workflow part of the site, based on the subdomain, correct key is picked from DB and used. This ensures that a user under sub1.mysite.com does not go to www.mysite.com for Google authentication.

Is this possible?

Comment: I can do something similar in Github. Use an existing key to add more keys.

Comment: not totally sure I understand the question, but if I do, how about having a single redirect URL then using the State parameter to do onward routing

Comment: The doesn't work in case the clients use something like ezproxy which changes the hostname. https://www.mysite.com.ezproxy.com. There is no way to redirect back to them. Thats why need separate redirects.